# Product queue for my subscription box

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce, subscription

I'm in the process of developing my subscription box and was struggling a bit with the available solutions on the backend of my site.

I only send one item (as a start) in my box every month and I want my customers to choose from my catalog of products what they want in a particular month. I was looking for a solution which makes it possible for customers to schedule what they want in the upcoming months. Some kind of “product queue” where they can rearrange, delete and add products. I can't really find any out-of-the-box solution for WooCommerce or Shopify and was hoping someone maybe could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!